# very weird Index Performance in sql server 12

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have a table facTableA. 
this table has one primary key composed of : IdDimRandomTable and IdDimDate

in the dev environnement, for some tests, i've been doing some purges of this table along with dozens of others.

but now my maintenance plan is blocked each time it gets to this table because now delete queries on this table take a lot of time( never saw one finish).

apparently nothing is locking the table. eveyday i insert on it hundred thousands of rows with no problem.

i've checked index fragmentation but it's <2%
and updated statistics

now simple select queries take a lot of time.

so what i was executing before is this
    delete top(1000) * from FacTableA
    where IdDimDate not in ( select IdDimDate from view )

but it runs indefinitely now.

```
select top(1) * from FacTableA
where IdDimDate not in ( select IdDimDate from view )
```

it takes a looooot of time > 20minutes ( never had the patience to finish one

vs

```
select top(1000) * from FacExposureMarket 
where IdDimDate not in ( select IdDimDate from view )
```

it takes lot less time ( between 2 minutes and 10 minutes)

vs

```
select  * from FacExposureMarket 
where IdDimDate not in ( select IdDimDate from vwTwoDisplayedDates)
```

takes ALL the lines in 38 secondes

i would have expected the opposite actually ? ( i even created a non clustered index on dimdate and used WITH(INDEX(NEWINDEXDIMDATE)) but it's slower than PK

Plus, we dropped a lot of tables and database seems to be slower than usual.

can shrinkdatabase ( with notruncate) be usefull in that case?

thanks for your help

Comment: Just to check - do you mean SQL Server 2014 (12.0) or SQL Server 2012 (11.0)?

Comment: SQL Server 2012 (11.0)

Comment: The symptom `runs indefinitely` sounds like blocking, not like fragmentation or outdated stats. While this is running indefinitely, what does `sys.dm_exec_requests` say is the wait type? Is there a value in `blocking_session_id`?

Comment: yes, that's what i thought of at first but no it's not that. the blocking session id is 0 of the request and also i don't  think it's that since select * works perfectly well. ( status running , wait type is null)